# Group by specific attribute in Django using ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model as below:

```
class Revenue(BaseModel):
    revenue_type = models.ForeignKey(RevenueType, blank=True, null=True, max_length=256, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='revenue')
    external_account_id = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=256)
    external_user_id = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=256)
```

Now I want to get all the `revenue`s `id`s but grouped by similar `external_account_id`.

Suppose the below are the model instances details:

```
revenue1 = Revenue("external_account_id": 1, "external_user_id": 1)
revenue2 = Revenue("external_account_id": 1, "external_user_id": 2)
revenue3 = Revenue("external_account_id": 1, "external_user_id": 3)
revenue4 = Revenue("external_account_id": 1, "external_user_id": 4)
revenue5 = Revenue("external_account_id": 2, "external_user_id": 5)
revenue6 = Revenue("external_account_id": 2, "external_user_id": 6)
revenue7 = Revenue("external_account_id": 3, "external_user_id": 7)
revenue8 = Revenue("external_account_id": 3, "external_user_id": 8)
revenue9 = Revenue("external_account_id": 4, "external_user_id": 9)
revenue10 = Revenue("external_account_id": 5, "external_user_id": 10)
```

I want the queryset or dict like this:

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 3: [7, 8], 4: [9], 5: [10]}
```

Where the keys are the `external_account_id` and the values are either `external_user_id` or `id`s of the model instances. How can I query for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the `external_account_id` and the `external_user_id`, and then work with [**`groupby(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to make groups, so:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = Revenue.objects.values(
    'external_account_id', 'external_user_id'
).order_by('external_account_id')

result = {
  k: [v['external_user_id'] for v in vs]
  for k, vs in groupby(data, itemgetter('external_account_id'))
}
```

That being said, I think that it is better to work with `ForeignKey`s, this filters more efficient, and will provide a lot of extra Django ORM tooling.

Comment: I thought of foreignkeys but these values come from external api and they only need to be stored in our system. So they are charfields.